# Invalid Method Varien_Data_Tree_Node::isInRootCategoryList

Tags: troubleshooting

Everything works in my local dev env, but after transfer to a staging server, nothing works in the frontend. Trying to access any page, I get the following report.

Backend is working fine.

```
a:5:{i:0;s:70:"Invalid method Varien_Data_Tree_Node::isInRootCategoryList(Array
(
)
)";i:1;s:5618:"#0 /var/www/staging.shop.myshop.com/web/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Helper/Category.php(123): Varien_Object->__call('isInRootCategor...', Array)
#1 /var/www/staging.shop.myshop.com/web/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Helper/Category.php(123): Varien_Data_Tree_Node->isInRootCategoryList()
#2 /var/www/staging.shop.myshop.com/web/app/code/community/ZetaPrints/AccessControl/Helper/Category.php(41): Mage_Catalog_Helper_Category->canShow(Object(Varien_Data_Tree_Node))
#3 /var/www/staging.shop.myshop.com/web/app/code/community/ZetaPrints/AccessControl/Helper/Category.php(67): ZetaPrints_AccessControl_Helper_Category->canShow(Object(Varien_Data_Tree_Node))
#4 /var/www/staging.shop.myshop.com/web/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Observer.php(217): ZetaPrints_AccessControl_Helper_Category->getStoreCategories()
#5 /var/www/staging.shop.myshop.com/web/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1338): Mage_Catalog_Model_Observer->addCatalogToTopmenuItems(Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#6 /var/www/staging.shop.myshop.com/web/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1317): Mage_Core_Model_App->_callObserverMethod(Object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Observer), 'addCatalogToTop...', Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#7 /var/www/staging.shop.myshop.com/web/app/Mage.php(456): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('page_block_html...', Array)
#8 /var/www/staging.shop.myshop.com/web/app/code/core/Mage/Page/Block/Html/Topmenu.php(74): Mage::dispatchEvent('page_block_html...', Array)
#9 /var/www/staging.shop.myshop.com/vendor/vendor/myshop-webshop/app/design/frontend/flatshop/default/template/page/html/topmenu.phtml(18): Mage_Page_Block_Html_Topmenu->getHtml('level-top')
#10 /var/www/staging.shop.myshop.com/web/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/var/www/stagin...')
#11 /var/www/staging.shop.myshop.com/web/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/flatsh...')
#12 /var/www/staging.shop.myshop.com/web/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#13 /var/www/staging.shop.myshop.com/web/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#14 /var/www/staging.shop.myshop.com/web/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Text/List.php(43): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#15 /var/www/staging.shop.myshop.com/web/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Text_List->_toHtml()
#16 /var/www/staging.shop.myshop.com/web/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(637): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#17 /var/www/staging.shop.myshop.com/web/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(581): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('topMenu', true)
#18 /var/www/staging.shop.myshop.com/vendor/vendor/myshop-webshop/app/design/frontend/flatshop/myshop/template/page/html/header.phtml(28): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('topMenu')
#19 /var/www/staging.shop.myshop.com/web/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/var/www/stagin...')
#20 /var/www/staging.shop.myshop.com/web/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/flatsh...')
#21 /var/www/staging.shop.myshop.com/web/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#22 /var/www/staging.shop.myshop.com/web/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#23 /var/www/staging.shop.myshop.com/web/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(637): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#24 /var/www/staging.shop.myshop.com/web/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(581): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('header', true)
#25 /var/www/staging.shop.myshop.com/vendor/vendor/myshop-webshop/app/design/frontend/flatshop/default/template/page/1column.phtml(35): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('header')
#26 /var/www/staging.shop.myshop.com/web/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/var/www/stagin...')
#27 /var/www/staging.shop.myshop.com/web/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/flatsh...')
#28 /var/www/staging.shop.myshop.com/web/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#29 /var/www/staging.shop.myshop.com/web/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#30 /var/www/staging.shop.myshop.com/web/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(555): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#31 /var/www/staging.shop.myshop.com/web/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(390): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
#32 /var/www/staging.shop.myshop.com/web/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Helper/Page.php(137): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
#33 /var/www/staging.shop.myshop.com/web/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Helper/Page.php(52): Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->_renderPage(Object(Mage_Cms_IndexController), 'home')
#34 /var/www/staging.shop.myshop.com/web/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/controllers/IndexController.php(45): Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->renderPage(Object(Mage_Cms_IndexController), 'home')
#35 /var/www/staging.shop.myshop.com/web/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Cms_IndexController->indexAction()
#36 /var/www/staging.shop.myshop.com/web/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#37 /var/www/staging.shop.myshop.com/web/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#38 /var/www/staging.shop.myshop.com/web/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#39 /var/www/staging.shop.myshop.com/web/app/Mage.php(692): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#40 /var/www/staging.shop.myshop.com/web/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#41 {main}";s:3:"url";s:1:"/";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:5:"eu_en";}
```

The template files causing the error is:

```
<?php
/**
 * Magento
 *
 * @category    design
 * @package     meigeetheme_default
 * @copyright   Copyright (c) 2012 MeigeeTeam. (http://www.meigeeteam.com)
 *
 *
 *
 * Template for Mage_Page_Block_Html
 */
?>
<?php 
/*****/
$sidebarPosition = MAGE::helper('ThemeOptionsFlatshop')->getThemeOptionsFlatshop('sidebar'); 
$custompatern = MAGE::helper('ThemeOptionsFlatshop')->getThemeOptionsFlatshop('custompatern');
$bgPatern = $paternurl = $mediaurl = "";
if (!$custompatern):
    $bgPatern = MAGE::helper('ThemeOptionsFlatshop')->getThemeOptionsFlatshop('patern');
else:
    $mediaurl = MAGE::helper('ThemeOptionsFlatshop')->getThemeOptionsFlatshop('mediaurl');
    $paternurl = 'style="background:url('.$mediaurl.$custompatern.') center top repeat;"';
endif;
/*****/
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="<?php echo $this->getLang() ?>">
<head>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('head') ?>
</head>
<body<?php echo $this->getBodyClass()?' class="'.$this->getBodyClass().'"':'' ?>>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('after_body_start') ?>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('global_notices') ?>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('header') ?>  // LINE 35 HERE
```

And

```
<?php
    $customlogo = MAGE::helper('ThemeOptionsFlatshop')->getThemeOptionsFlatshop('customlogo');
    $mediaurl = MAGE::helper('ThemeOptionsFlatshop')->getThemeOptionsFlatshop('mediaurl');
?>
<header id="header">
    <div class="container_12">
        <div class="grid_12">
            <?php if($this->getWelcome()): ?>
                <p class="welcome-msg"><?php echo $this->getChildHtml('welcome') ?> <?php echo $this->getAdditionalHtml() ?></p>
            <?php endif; ?>
           <?php if ($customlogo['logo_status'] == 0): ?>
                <h1 class="logo"><strong><?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?></strong><a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('') ?>" title="<?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?>" class="logo"><img src="<?php echo $this->getLogoSrc() ?>" <?php echo MAGE::helper('ThemeOptionsFlatshop/Retina')->getRetinaData('logo'); ?> alt="<?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?>" /></a></h1>
                <?php else:?>
                <h1 class="logo"><strong><?php echo $customlogo['logo_alt']; ?></strong><a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('') ?>" title="<?php echo $customlogo['logo_alt']; ?>" class="logo"><img src="<?php echo $mediaurl.$customlogo['logo']; ?>" <?php echo MAGE::helper('ThemeOptionsFlatshop/Retina')->getRetinaData('logo_custom'); ?> alt="<?php echo $customlogo['logo_alt']; ?>" /></a></h1>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topMenu') ?>  // PROBLEM LINE
```

Any insight what might be causing the issue or how should can I troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

one of your extensions (`ZetaPrints_AccessControl`) is badly written.
it works with flat categories disabled but it does not work with it enabled (or the other way around).
The quick solution is to look for this setting on your local machine and set it the same on live. (`system->configuration->catalog->frontend`)
But this is bad. You should remove that extension or try to make it work with both values for that specific setting